# What to do next if survey sample cannot pass the chi-square representativeness test?

Tags: sampling

Suppose a survey sample (obtained by stratified random sampling) can pass the chi-square representativeness tests on some variables but not the others. It seems to me there may be several solutions:

1. Draw another sample, but this is costly and time consuming.
2. Drop the outliers that make the tests to fail, i.e., assigning zero weight to the observations that make the sample look non-representative.
3. Re-weight the original sample to achieve representativeness. But what kind of weights should I use?
4. Draw more observations and add to the original sample? But this seems to change my original sampling design.

Any suggestions and text books/academic paper references would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this depends on what statistic you are measuring.
For eg. If you want to estimate the height of students in a school, the variables like age and gender must be properly represented but it is ok if some like marks, eye color are not represented.
You must first find what variables are affecting the measured statistic.